# Return a local variable from a Module containing a Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, scoping

I would like to create a set of custom controls that call Manipulate[] and return the value(s) set during the Manipulate session.

I can easily make a version that uses something like:

```
MyControl[] := Manipulate[...{a, -10,10}, {b,-1,1}]
```

This works but variables a, b and any additional variables set by Manipulate are global.

Is it possible to do something like this (Return a Dataset with the selected values for a and b when a "Set" button is clicked and Return Null if "Forget" is clicked):

```
MyControl[]:= Module[ {a, b},
                      Manipulate[...{a, -10, 10}, {b, -1, 1},
                                 Button["Set", Return[Dataset[Association @ {aValue->a, bValue->b}]]],
Button["Forget", Return[]]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you certain that `a` and `b` in the first example are Global?  In version 10 they do not appear to be:

[image]

(The sliders of one `Manipulate` do not affect those of the other.)

A look at the Cell Expression for one of these shows:

```
. . . DynamicModuleBox[{$CellContext`a$$ = -3.3999999999999995`, $CellContext`b$$ = 
0.21999999999999997`, . . .] . . .
```

It would seem that these are already localized with [`DynamicModule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DynamicModule.html).

Comment: Hi Mr. Wizard - I see them as global because I can see the values of a and b from the notebook that calls MyControl[].  I would like a and b to only be visible as a Dataset returned from MyControl[].  I would like a and b to only have definition inside MyControl[].

Comment: I'm using DynamicModule[...] around my Manipulate[] and all Manipulate[] variables are visible and settable in the notebook calling MyControl[].  I have set LocalizeVariables->True and all variables used by Manipulate are visible and settable from the calling notebook.